# Using Google Apps Script to find Docs/Slides/Sheets in all folders (and subfolders)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-slides

Starting with a link to a folder I'm trying to get info on all Docs/Slides/Sheets in that folder, the subfolders (and subfolders of subfolders).

With some online searching I finally got some code that will find ALL FILES, but I need to modify it to ONLY find Docs, Slides, and Sheets. What would be the best way to do that?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
function generateFolderTree(my_id) {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(my_id);
  var f = parentFolder.getFiles();
  Logger.log(f.next().getName())

  getChildFolders(parentFolder);
}

function getChildFolders(parent) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) { 
      Logger.log(files.next().getName()); // Print list of files inside the folder
    }
    getChildFolders(childFolder); // Recursive call for any sub-folders
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I wound up using and it seems to be doing everything I wanted/needed:

```
function getFolders() {
  var my_link = Browser.inputBox('Enter Folder Link', 'Paste a folder link below...', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  var my_id = getIdFromUrl(my_link);
  fcount = 2;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Im looking for SLIDES.", "WORKING...",600);
  generateFolderTree(my_id,MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Im looking for DOCS.", "WORKING...",600);
  generateFolderTree(my_id,MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Im looking for SHEETS.", "WORKING...",600);
  generateFolderTree(my_id,MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Your search is complete!", "FINISHED!");
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function generateFolderTree(my_id,type) {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(my_id);
  var f = parentFolder.getFilesByType(type);
  while (f.hasNext()) {
    file = f.next();
    display(file);
  }
  getChildFolders(parentFolder,type);
}

function getChildFolders(parent,type) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var files = childFolder.getFilesByType(type);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      mfs = files.next();
      display(mfs);
    }
    getChildFolders(childFolder,type); // Recursive call for any sub-folders
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of playing around with this i'm **positive** you could implement it into your code ;)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type

```
// Use MimeType enum to log the name of every Google Doc in the user's Drive.
var docs = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
while (docs.hasNext()) {
var doc = docs.next();
Logger.log(doc.getName())
}

// Use plain string to log the size of every PNG in the user's Drive.
var pngs = DriveApp.getFilesByType('image/png');
while (pngs.hasNext()) {
var png = pngs.next();
Logger.log(png.getSize());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    function myFunction() 
    {
        var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Projects");
        var folder = folders.next();
        var sheets = getFilesInFolderByType(folder, MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
        var docs = getFilesInFolderByType(folder, MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
        for each (var sheet in sheets)
        {
            console.log(sheet);
        }
        for each (var doc in docs)
        {
            console.log(doc);
        }
    }

    function getFilesInFolderByType(folder, type)
    {
        var files = []
        var filesInFolder = folder.getFilesByType(type);
        while (filesInFolder.hasNext())
        {
            files.push(filesInFolder.next());
        }
        // Use method to recurse through sub folders.
        var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
        while (subFolders.hasNext())
        { 
            var fileArray = getFilesInFolderByType(subFolders.next(), type);
            files.concat(fileArray);
        } 
        return files;
    }
```